# How can I initialize an SSD?

Tags: macbook-pro

I got a ssd, and I am trying to clone it with the hard drive. I am trying to use super duper! When I plug the ssd in, it says that the drive is not initialized, so i cant select it to copy to. When I go to disk utility, the partition option is greyed out. What do I need to do to make the drive readable so that it can be selected in the program? It's a wd blue 1tb.

Edit:
[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Mind showing a picture of what you see in Disk Utility? Just use the edit command above this comment to make the question read like you included this in the details.

Comment: Can't you reinitialize the ssd?  is there currently anything on it??

Comment: Just format it, that should be available, is it not?

Comment: What happens if you choose ‘Erase’ on the toolbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. I just needed to press erase, and that opened up the option to format it.